# Symbol for blanks as ambiguous bits

Tags: symbols, number

I display bit strings with ambiguous bits, like 11-101-0011---10-1-1. So, "-" means could be "1" or "0".

All symbols I tried like squares, circles display in a nonsymmetric fashion, e.g., `$001\square110\square\square0\square1$`
[image] displayes  wider space between "1" and \square than it does between "0" and \square or between two \squares. That's what I mean by 'nonsymmetric fashion'.

Note: square symbol may be replaced with a more suitable symbol.
.

How can I display these blanks suggestively, perhaps notation from bit algebra or logic?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "display unsemetrical".

Comment: Please add: A) at least one screenshot, showing what you call "unsymmetry", B) add your minimal Latex-code (without it's just like asking for repair without providing the defective device ;-)

Comment: With standard fonts the `1` is as wide as the `0`, that's why there looks to be more place around `1`. Howevr, I'd say this is a "good" quality in this situation, so that sequences with the same number of bits have the same length. In fact, you might want to use a symbol with the very same width for the ambiguous bit.

Comment: Thanks @Mico By "display unsemetrical" I mean that the output has different lengths of spaces between symbol and 1, and between symbol and 0. This occured with all symbols I tried like  ` \square` , ` \circle`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bit of “asymmetry” is unavoidable, because fonts commonly have the same bounding box for the digits, but the digit 1 is a bit narrower than 0.

Here's a way to get an empty rectangle which has the same bounding box as the digits, with also some sidebearings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ubit}{%
  \mathord{%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \makebox[\fontcharwd\textfont0 `0]{%
      \fbox{\kern-3\fboxrule\phantom{0}\kern-3\fboxrule}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$0 0 1 \ubit 1 1 0 \ubit \ubit 0 \ubit 1$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what I get if `\phantom{0}` is replaced by `0`:

[image]

Some more work would be needed if you need this at different font sizes.

Answer (score 6):

Is a solution with `verbatim` and `-` acceptable for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\verb|11-101-0011---10-1-1|

\verb|-010-0-00-1-0--10-1-|

\verb|01-10-1110-00-1-0-10|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea (+1) but I'd remove the `ams` packages, as they are not necessary for the answer. (I know you know, and we both know any article with serious math benefits from them, but I prefer not to have "unnecessary" code in answers.)

Comment: @campa Done, thanks!

Comment: Yes @CarLaTeX, that's also very helpful, thanks!